# OracleCommand Class and SqlScript Issue

Tags: c#, oraclecommand

I am trying to run the following query using a `OracleCommand` class.

But but I get this error:

> "ORA-00920 invalid relational operator".

I am sure it is to do with the date values. But do not know how to fix it. could you help?

```
  select s.store_code,count(i.invc_sid) as count 
  from invoice_v i 
  Left join store_v s 
     ON i.sbs_no and i.store_no = s.store_no 
  Where(i.created_date between to_date('02//01//2014','MM//DD//YY') 
       and to_date('02//28//2014','MM//DD//YY'))  
       and i.proc_status not in ('131072','65536','147456', '81920') 
       and i.invc_type = 0 AND i.sbs_no = 6  
  GROUP BY  s.store_code";
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be this `ON i.sbs_no and ` ... surely you mean `ON i.sbs_no =  SomeValue and ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in following line

```
Left join store_v s 
     ON i.sbs_no and i.store_no = s.store_no
```

Here, after **'ON'** you have written only `i.sbs_no` .

There should be something after this to compare like

```
ON i.sbs_no = 'Something' and i.store_no = s.store_no
```